# How are exceptions propagated by static blocks?

Tags: java, static-initialization

```
static {
    MessageDigest d;
    try {
        d = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD80"); <-- MD80 is no valid algorithm
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    hasher = d;
}
```

JVM will automatically execute these static initialiation statements when the class is loaded into JVM. That means, `runtimeexception` exception was thrown at load time.

Now, if I run such a class ( via eclipse ) I get a flood of exceptions originating from static blocks in the console.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MD8 MessageDigest not available
    at BloomFilter.<clinit>(BloomFilter.java:86)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: MD8 MessageDigest not available
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:142)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:659)
    at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:129)
    at BloomFilter.<clinit>(BloomFilter.java:84)
```

But, here is the doubt. This exception was thrown at 'load time'.
How was it displayed at runtime in the console ?
Was this exception thrown and stored somewhere between 'load' and 'runtime' ?

Basically I am looking to understand what happens between 'loadtime and runtime' once the exception has been thrown in static block ?

Comment: There is no "load time". The classes are loaded and initialized, lazily, at runtime.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "load time" - there is only "runtime". When the JVM starts, it determines which classes it needs to load; static initializes are executed whenever they need to be; for example right after loading the class.

Answer (score 2):

This exception was thrown at runtime. There is no concept of storing the exception. Basically static initialization block is executed just once sequentially line by line when the class get loaded for the first time i.e. class is referred/object is created etc.

I think by load time, you mean compile time. At compile time, compiler would just check whether your java code is syntactically correct or not. It wont execute any of the code. It would just compile your code and prepare byte code i.e. .class file for you.